# Grouping posts by date

Tags: php, date

I am trying to group my posts on the index page by date. For example:
Date 1

Post 1
 Post 2
 Post 3

Date 2

Post 1
Post 2
 Post 3

For some reason, I keep getting the posts under each date.  Here is my code, I cant work out where I am going wrong

```
<?php
$args = array('posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'date' );
$myQuery = new WP_Query($args);
$date = '';
if ( $myQuery->have_posts() ) : while ( $myQuery->have_posts() ) : $myQuery- 
>the_post();
if ( $date != get_the_date() ) {
echo $date;
} ?>
<time class="post-date" datetime="<?php the_time('Y-m-d'); ?>"><?php 
the_time('F jS, Y') ?></time>
<?php
$categories = get_the_category();
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    echo '<div class="row">
    <div class="column left"><a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( 
$category ) ) . '">
    <img src="' . esc_url( 'http://example.com/icons/' . intval( $category- 
>term_id ) . '.png' ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( $category->name ) . '" /></a> 
</div>'; 
}
?>

<div class="column right"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
<?php 
endwhile; endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: "I keep getting the posts under each date" Isn't that what you want to do? What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
$day_check = '';
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
  $day = get_the_date('j');
  if ($day != $day_check) {
    if ($day_check != '') {
      echo '</ul>'; // close the list here
    }
    echo get_the_date() . '<ul>';
  }
?>
<li><a href="#"><?php the_time(); ?><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php 
$day_check = $day;
endwhile; ?>
```

do like this i hop this work